# How to suppress Jersey exceptions that Jersey throws automatically?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

I am using Jersey 1.14 for REST in JAVA. If there is any error in POST body of a resource, Jersey throws and exception which mentions my internal classes to client. 
I continue wanting to give them error when the error is passed from my application, but suppress errors that are being thrown by Jersey(for the requests which does not even get to my application, as Jersey identifies the exception and throw it). 
I searched for any flag to achieve this, but could not find anything. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: 
Rephrasing the question: mute/suppress error stack trace for invalid input in jersey

UPDATE:
I tried using ExceptionMapper, catching java.lang.Exception. It catches excpetion like when there is Content-Type missing, but fails to catch exception when there is an error in object conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *ExceptionMapper*. Here's [an old article](http://yiyujia.blogspot.pt/2011/10/simple-tutorial-about-exception.html) about it that will do.

Comment: I tried this. But it is working in the case when say Content-Type is missing, but not in the case where there is an error in object conversion.
It still throws an error: Unrecognized field "xyz" (and a class stack trace after this)

Comment: I found what the exception is. It is throwing JsonMappingException.
But the problem now is, there is already a ExceptionMapper class taking JsonMappingException, and at the time of registering the mapper, it sometimes register my mapper, and sometimes mapper of library

Answer (score 0):

Jersey will throw exceptions which are not handled in your code. So you need to wrap your webservice code in `try/catch`. And catch the `Exception` class in to make sure that you handle it gracefully in your web service class.

Comment: I will not get a chance to throw an exception, as Jersey will raise exception as it will not be able to create instance of input object from the input value. Is there a way to intercept Jersey exception? There is one ExceptionMapper interface, however that also intercepts the exceptions thrown by the method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be achieved through *server* configuration, since Jersey does not seem to have any relevant [configuration option](http://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/appendix-properties.html).

Which servlet container are you using?

---

(EDIT) For Tomcat search for "tomcat suppress exception stack trace". Most answers will have you place an `error-page` element in your `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/your-custom-error-page.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

And, of course, implement a `your-custom-error-page.jsp` that does not include the stack trace. It may also check application environment and present the stack trace only in DEVELOPMENT.

Comment: I am using SpringServlet. Even I went through configuration options and didn't find anything.

Comment: SpringServlet is part of the framework, it would run on any J(2)EE servlet container. I mean the server (Tomcat probably? JBoss? Websphere? etc...)

Comment: oh, I am using tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing xml you can write a custom ContextResolver to catch the exception. I case of json you may need a messagebodyreader/writer